# Ubuntu 20.10 freezes

Tags: freeze, 20.10, amd-ryzen

My desktop (not laptop) with Ubuntu froze 3 or 4 times yesterday (it freezes for a minute or so and then keep working as before). That's what I can see in logs:

```
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831149] [TTM] Buffer eviction failed
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831158] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831158] refcount_t: underflow; use-after-free.
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831169] WARNING: CPU: 8 PID: 2470 at lib/refcount.c:28 refcount_warn_saturate+0xae/0xf0
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831169] Modules linked in: veth xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo nft_counter xt_addrtype nft_compat nft_chain_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c br_netfilter bridge stp llc nf_tables nfnetlink aufs overlay nls_iso8859_1 input_leds joydev snd_hda_codec_realtek edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep kvm snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel nouveau snd_rawmidi mxm_wmi ttm aesni_intel eeepc_wmi asus_wmi snd_seq sparse_keymap crypto_simd drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device cec cryptd glue_helper rc_core rapl snd_timer video i2c_algo_bit efi_pstore fb_sys_fops wmi_bmof snd syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt k10temp soundcore ccp mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev drm lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid r8169 realtek crc32_pclmul i2c_piix4 nvme ahci xhci_pci nvme_core
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831196]  xhci_pci_renesas libahci wmi gpio_amdpt gpio_generic
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831199] CPU: 8 PID: 2470 Comm: Xorg Not tainted 5.8.0-41-generic #46-Ubuntu
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831199] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/PRIME B450M-K, BIOS 2409 12/02/2020
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831201] RIP: 0010:refcount_warn_saturate+0xae/0xf0
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831202] Code: d8 3f 6a 01 01 e8 e7 7f b1 ff 0f 0b 5d c3 80 3d c5 3f 6a 01 00 75 91 48 c7 c7 00 48 df 87 c6 05 b5 3f 6a 01 01 e8 c7 7f b1 ff <0f> 0b 5d c3 80 3d a3 3f 6a 01 00 0f 85 6d ff ff ff 48 c7 c7 58 48
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831202] RSP: 0018:ffffb6030352fcc8 EFLAGS: 00010282
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831203] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000002 RCX: ffff96f04ec18cd8
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831204] RDX: 00000000ffffffd8 RSI: 0000000000000027 RDI: ffff96f04ec18cd0
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831204] RBP: ffffb6030352fcc8 R08: 0000000000000004 R09: 00000000000004a1
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831204] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000004
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831205] R13: ffff96efecd87000 R14: ffff96f02e50e800 R15: ffff96f02e9fa000
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831206] FS:  00007f0a893f8a40(0000) GS:ffff96f04ec00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831206] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831207] CR2: 00007fd23fffebb8 CR3: 0000000746afc000 CR4: 0000000000340ee0
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831207] Call Trace:
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831213]  ttm_bo_put+0x3f/0x50 [ttm]
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831244]  nouveau_gem_new+0x8a/0x120 [nouveau]
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831267]  ? nouveau_gem_new+0x120/0x120 [nouveau]
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831287]  nouveau_gem_ioctl_new+0x5b/0xd0 [nouveau]
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831307]  ? nouveau_gem_new+0x120/0x120 [nouveau]
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831317]  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xae/0xf0 [drm]
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831325]  drm_ioctl+0x238/0x3d0 [drm]
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831344]  ? nouveau_gem_new+0x120/0x120 [nouveau]
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831365]  nouveau_drm_ioctl+0x66/0xc0 [nouveau]
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831367]  ksys_ioctl+0x8e/0xc0
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831368]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x1a/0x20
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831370]  do_syscall_64+0x49/0xc0
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831372]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831373] RIP: 0033:0x7f0a8985d31b
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831374] Code: 89 d8 49 8d 3c 1c 48 f7 d8 49 39 c4 72 b5 e8 1c ff ff ff 85 c0 78 ba 4c 89 e0 5b 5d 41 5c c3 f3 0f 1e fa b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 1d 3b 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831375] RSP: 002b:00007fff8ce4ba98 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831375] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007fff8ce4baf0 RCX: 00007f0a8985d31b
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831376] RDX: 00007fff8ce4baf0 RSI: 00000000c0306480 RDI: 0000000000000010
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831376] RBP: 00000000c0306480 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000055bcdcf74130
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831376] R10: 00000000000002ba R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007fff8ce4baf0
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831377] R13: 0000000000000010 R14: 000055bcdc6c5340 R15: 0000000000001000
Feb  1 11:07:14 maxim-RZ kernel: [175305.831378] ---[ end trace 0e41bfa77c9fd628 ]---
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Feb  1 11:08:50 maxim-RZ systemd-modules-load[368]: Inserted module 'lp'
Feb  1 11:08:50 maxim-RZ systemd-modules-load[368]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Feb  1 11:08:50 maxim-RZ systemd-modules-load[368]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
```

I am googling right now trying to understand what it is about but maybe somebody here will be able to help me understand what is the source of those freezes.

Desktop uses Ryzen 5 3600 (if that matters).

The swap is on:

```
cat /proc/swaps
Filename                Type        Size        Used        Priority
/swapfile                               file        4194300     0       -2
```

`sudo journalctl` gives same results I posted here (same error, same details).

Comment: Do you have swap space? Read `man mkswap swapon`.

Comment: Look at the logs. `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` (adjust the "5", read `man journalctl`).

Comment: I'm having a similar issue in 2 of my computers. Both with an Nvidia graphics card. I didn't wait 1 min, to see if they unfreeze, but will do the next time. I've just restarted them until now... Will be back with more info the next time it freezes, which is as well a couple of times per day.

Comment: It happened today again to me. Just once, since last time I wrote here. Which is an improvement, perhaps some people is doing a great work in those updates I keep receiving. Anyway, the only 'solution' I've been able to find, is to press CONTROL + ALT + F1, so I'm moved to the Ubuntu login screen. And from there, I can safely restart the PC. At least, I don't have to press the restart button from the PC, which does't safely close all the open apps.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] I fixed an issue by replacing video card. Initially it was NVidia GeForce 210 (yep, simpliest card I had at that moment). It had issues with properly detecting my display so I switched from NVidia 340 driver to nouveau driver and set 2550x1440R mode manually). It was working but I guess this card just can't handle such resolution and it caused those issues). I replaced video card with AMD RX 550 and issue gone. Thank you for all your comments.